# Constexpr constructor for a struct with bitfields

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, constexpr, bit-fields

```
struct data {
    uint8_t nibble1 : 4,
        nibble2 : 4;
    constexpr data() {
        nibble1 = 2;
        nibble2 = 4;
    }
};
```

This gives me the following two compilation errors on GCC 9.2.0:

```
error: member 'data::nibble1' must be initialized by mem-initializer in 'constexpr' constructor
error: member 'data::nibble2' must be initialized by mem-initializer in 'constexpr' constructor
```

But I'm pretty sure my constructor intialises both of them. I've taken a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr and I don't see any requirements which my constexpr constructor doesn't satisfy.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You are *assigning* to both of them. You are not *initializing* them with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the members with a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
constexpr data() : nibble1(2), nibble2(4) { }
```

---

The page you linked show the following requirements for `constexpr` constructors:

> - for the constructor of a class or struct, every base class sub-object and every non-variant non-static data member must be initialized.

But this:

```
nibble1 = 2;
```

...is not an initialization for `nibble1`, it's an assignment. The only way to initialize member variables is to use a member initializer list or to default them (which is not possible for bit-fields until C++20 I think).